# bower installs archive version of packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bower

I have npm 3.3.6 and bower 1.6.8 on Windows 10. Whenever I try to install any package such as jquery of framework7, it downloads and installs and archive version of the package. See e.g.

```
> bower install jquery --save
bower jquery#*              not-cached git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#*
bower jquery#*                 resolve git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#*
bower jquery#*                download https://github.com/jquery/jquery/archive/1.11.3.tar.gz
bower jquery#*                 extract archive.tar.gz
bower jquery#*                resolved git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#1.11.3
bower jquery#~1.11.3           install jquery#1.11.3
```

What is wrong? How can I install the latest packages instead? I tried to clean both npm and bower cache but it did not help.

EDIT:

you can see my `bower.json` and the install response

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2.1.0"
  }
}
```

response:

```
bower install
bower jquery#~2.1.0         not-cached git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#~2.1.0
bower jquery#~2.1.0            resolve git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#~2.1.0
bower jquery#~2.1.0       ENORESTARGET No tag found that was able to satisfy ~2.1.0

Additional error details:
Available versions in git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git: 1.11.3, 1.11.2, 1.11.1, 1.11.1-rc2, 1.11.1-rc1, 1.11.1-beta1, 1.11.0, 1.11.0-rc1, 1.11.0-beta3, 1.11.0-beta2, 1.11.0-beta1, 1.10.2, 1.10.1, 1.10.0, 1.10.0-beta1, 1.4.4, 1.4.3, 1.4.2, 1.4.1, 1.4.0, 1.3.2, 1.3.1, 1.3.0, 1.2.6, 1.2.5, 1.2.4, 1.2.3, 1.2.2, 1.2.1, 1.1.4, 1.1.3, 1.1.2, 1.1.1, 1.0.4, 1.0.3, 1.0.2, 1.0.1
```

Comment: Look at `bower.json` in the root dir there you can configure what version you want for the packages

Comment: See my edit, it cannot find the latest jquery

Answer (score 0):

Set this in `bower.json`:

```
"jquery": "~2.1.0",
```

This will fetch the latest from the jQuery series 2.1.x (currently 2.1.4).

If you need a different series, you can change this accordingly. If you need an exact version, just remove the tilde from the beginning.

By the way jQuery 1.11.3 is the latest version from jQuery series 1.x.x.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried but got error. See my edited question. Any help?

Comment: You should try the clean the bower cache. Also, check your firewall, if you have one.

Comment: I have cleaned both npm and bower cache. I have also tried two different internet connections (cable, 4g). I do not have any firewall just what Windows 10 has built in

Comment: What does `bower info jquery` and `bower info jquery#~2.1.0` say?

Comment: Then I am out of ideas, The only difference I could find between our setups was the npm version. It works for me after upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Try `"jquery": "~2",` in `bower.json` this will install latest minor version starting from the major version 2